# Why does c# string.TrimStart trim trailing spaces of the parameter?

Tags: c#, trim

In code:

```
string s = "Executing".TrimStart(@"Exec ".ToCharArray());
```

or

```
string s = "Executing".TrimStart("Exec ".ToCharArray());
```

s will equal **"uting"** in spite of the trailing space character while

```
bool t = "Executing".StartsWith("Exec ");
```

t will equal False?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `char[]` argument to `TrimStart` implies a *set of characters*, not a *string*.  In other words it will remove all the consecutive characters from the start of the string that are in the `char[]` array -- it will *not* check that the characters match the sequence of characters in the array.  (If it did do that, wouldn't it make more sense for it to accept a `string`?)

Comment: So TrimStart means Trim all characters from the input string until the first character not in the set is encountered.  Correct?